# Cannot cast class A to class B

Tags: java, oop

What is the proper way to access the field `level` from instance of `Minotaur`?
Getting error in `for (int i =0 ; i < ((Monster) this).level ; i++)` which is `Cannot cast from Player to Monster`.

```
package player;

import monsters.*;

public class Player extends GameCharacter {

      public void performAttackOn(GameCharacter who){

    if (who instanceof Monster ){

        for (int i =0 ; i < ((Monster) this).level ; i++) { // << 

                 }

    public static  class Minotaur extends Monster{ // << nested class which is being created and there is need to access it's level

        public Minotaur () {

              type = "Minotaur";

        }
    }

}
```

---

```
package monsters;

public class Monster extends GameCharacter{

    public int level = 1;
}
```

---

```
package monsters;

public abstract class GameCharacter{

public static  class Minotaur extends Monster{

        public Minotaur(){
            type = "Minotaur";
             hitPoints = 30;
             weapon = new Weapon.Sword();

        }
    }
}
```

---

`Minotaur` should extend `monsters.GameCharacter`, `monsters.Monster` and override in `Player.player` some  methods which was inherited from `monsters.GameCharacter`

Comment: It's simple, you don't. Player is a GameCharacter, not a  Monster. So Player is not going to cast properly to a Monster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the `GameCharacter` interface define a `getLevel()` method which `Monster` and `Player` both implement.

```
public interface GameCharacter
{
  public int getLevel( );
}
```

Once you've done that, you're taking advantage of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) and don't even need to cast.

---

Also, do you really mean to cast `this` which is of type `Player`, to type `Monster`? Or do you mean:

```
public void performAttackOn(GameCharacter who)
{
    for (int i =0 ; i < who.getLevel( ) ; i++)
    {
      // do stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the hierarchy you have defined, a `Player` can never be a `Monster` so the cast is impossible.

I believe the line you are having issues with, based on the check above it, should reference `who` instead of `this`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ((Monster)who).level; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty easy. You check if `who` is a Monter but if yes, you cast `this` to Moster and `this` refers to object in witch you currently are, it means some Player. replace this

`((Monster) this).level`

with this

`((Monster) who).level`

and the error should dissaper.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Now I see, you can't have inheritance on fields of classes. You should have a common method

```
pubic int level();
```

in your `GameCharacter`. Then it's your choice if to define `level` as two different fields of children classes (not recommended) or just leave to `GameCharacter` to have a level field.

here: `((Monster) this).level` you are casting the `this` instance, which is a `Player` to `Monster`. That's why you get the error.

Maybe you meant:

```
if (who instanceof Monster ){
  for (int i =0 ; i < ((Monster) who).level ; i++) { // << 

  }
}
```